# Why is there a limit for the former and no limit for the latter?

Tags: calculus, limits

One problem about the limit of the function. It's very confusing to me:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} =\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos|x|-1}{x}
=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}|x|^2}{x}=0$$ Then the answer say the limit is existed.

But in the other equal:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos\sqrt{|x|}-1}{x} 
= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{|x|})^2}{x}
=-\frac{1}{2}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{x}}$$

Then the answer say they have no limits!

I really don't know why, and I think these equal is similar, the numerator is always non-negative, only can change plus or minus in the denominator, why the one has limit and the other one didn't?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: f(x) is an abstract function, this is a problem I had recently when I was learning about limits of functions.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean ' an abstract function'. Take $f(x) = x$ then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) -f(0)}{x} = 1 \ne 0$

Comment: Sorry, that's my problem, I made a mistake. Actually, f(x) is cos|x| in former equal. I'm getting mixed up.

Comment: That limit exists iff $f$ is derivable at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of your question is why it is claimed that the following limit does not exist.

${\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{x}}$

If you consider $x>0$ then $\frac{|x|}{x} = \frac{x}{x} = 1$ so the limit as you approach from positive x is 1.

On the other hand, for $x<0$ then $\frac{|x|}{x} = \frac{-x}{x} = -1$ so the limit as you approach from negative x is -1.

As the limit is not the same from the two directions, there is no well-defined limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the two graphs, the difference should be clear.  In one the limit is zero whether $x \to 0$ through positive or negative numbers.  In the other, when $x$ approaches zero only through positive values the limit is $-1/2$ and only through negative numbers the limits is $+1/2$. These not being equal means the limit as $x \to 0$ in an arbitrary manner dos not exist.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

First note that the Taylor series for $\cos x$ is
$$
\cos x = 1 -x^2/2! + x^/4! +\cdots
$$
Since $ \cos x = \cos (-x)$ it follows that $\cos x = \cos |x|$. Since the Taylor series for $\cos x = 1 -x^2/2! + x^/4! +\cdots $ it is easy to observe that
$$
\frac{ \cos x - 1}{x} = -x/2 + x^3/24 + \cdots 
$$ then it follows that the given limit is $0$. In your case since $ |x|^2  = x^2$ so $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|^2} {x} = 0$.

In latter case since $|x| = - x$ for negative $x$ we will have $|x|/x = -1$ and for positive $x$ we have $|x|/x = 1$